# Indexing ranked permutations into other ranked permutations

Tags: algorithm, math, language-agnostic, permutation, combinatorics

I'm considering all permutations of 0, ..., n-1 in lexicographic order. I'm given two ranks, i and j, and asked to find the rank of the permutation that results from applying the i'th permutation to the j'th permutation.

A couple examples for n=3:

p(3) = [1, 2, 0], p(4) = [2, 0, 1], result = [0, 1, 2], rank = 0

Given i = j = 4, we get [2, 0, 1] applied to itself is [1, 2, 0], rank = 3.

What I've come up with so far: I convert the ranks to their respective permutations via Lehmer codes, calculate the desired permutation, and convert back to rank via Lehmer codes.

Can anyone suggest a way to get the rank of the desired permutation from the other two ranks, without having to actually calculate the permutations? Storing the n! x n! array is not an option.

-edit- Note that I'm not wedded to lexicographic order if some other ordering would enable this.

-edit- Here are the n! by n! grids for n=3 & 4, for lexicographic ranks. Row i is indexed into column j to get the output. Note that the n=3 grid is identical to the top-left corner of the n=4 grid.

```
00|01|02|03|04|05|
01|00|03|02|05|04|
02|04|00|05|01|03|
03|05|01|04|00|02|
04|02|05|00|03|01|
05|03|04|01|02|00|

00|01|02|03|04|05|06|07|08|09|10|11|12|13|14|15|16|17|18|19|20|21|22|23|
01|00|03|02|05|04|07|06|09|08|11|10|13|12|15|14|17|16|19|18|21|20|23|22|
02|04|00|05|01|03|08|10|06|11|07|09|14|16|12|17|13|15|20|22|18|23|19|21|
03|05|01|04|00|02|09|11|07|10|06|08|15|17|13|16|12|14|21|23|19|22|18|20|
04|02|05|00|03|01|10|08|11|06|09|07|16|14|17|12|15|13|22|20|23|18|21|19|
05|03|04|01|02|00|11|09|10|07|08|06|17|15|16|13|14|12|23|21|22|19|20|18|
06|07|12|13|18|19|00|01|14|15|20|21|02|03|08|09|22|23|04|05|10|11|16|17|
07|06|13|12|19|18|01|00|15|14|21|20|03|02|09|08|23|22|05|04|11|10|17|16|
08|10|14|16|20|22|02|04|12|17|18|23|00|05|06|11|19|21|01|03|07|09|13|15|
09|11|15|17|21|23|03|05|13|16|19|22|01|04|07|10|18|20|00|02|06|08|12|14|
10|08|16|14|22|20|04|02|17|12|23|18|05|00|11|06|21|19|03|01|09|07|15|13|
11|09|17|15|23|21|05|03|16|13|22|19|04|01|10|07|20|18|02|00|08|06|14|12|
12|18|06|19|07|13|14|20|00|21|01|15|08|22|02|23|03|09|10|16|04|17|05|11|
13|19|07|18|06|12|15|21|01|20|00|14|09|23|03|22|02|08|11|17|05|16|04|10|
14|20|08|22|10|16|12|18|02|23|04|17|06|19|00|21|05|11|07|13|01|15|03|09|
15|21|09|23|11|17|13|19|03|22|05|16|07|18|01|20|04|10|06|12|00|14|02|08|
16|22|10|20|08|14|17|23|04|18|02|12|11|21|05|19|00|06|09|15|03|13|01|07|
17|23|11|21|09|15|16|22|05|19|03|13|10|20|04|18|01|07|08|14|02|12|00|06|
18|12|19|06|13|07|20|14|21|00|15|01|22|08|23|02|09|03|16|10|17|04|11|05|
19|13|18|07|12|06|21|15|20|01|14|00|23|09|22|03|08|02|17|11|16|05|10|04|
20|14|22|08|16|10|18|12|23|02|17|04|19|06|21|00|11|05|13|07|15|01|09|03|
21|15|23|09|17|11|19|13|22|03|16|05|18|07|20|01|10|04|12|06|14|00|08|02|
22|16|20|10|14|08|23|17|18|04|12|02|21|11|19|05|06|00|15|09|13|03|07|01|
23|17|21|11|15|09|22|16|19|05|13|03|20|10|18|04|07|01|14|08|12|02|06|00|
```

Here are the factoradics for n=4. I left off the last digit, which is always zero, for compactness.

```
000|001|010|011|020|021|100|101|110|111|120|121|200|201|210|211|220|221|300|301|310|311|320|321|
001|000|011|010|021|020|101|100|111|110|121|120|201|200|211|210|221|220|301|300|311|310|321|320|
010|020|000|021|001|011|110|120|100|121|101|111|210|220|200|221|201|211|310|320|300|321|301|311|
011|021|001|020|000|010|111|121|101|120|100|110|211|221|201|220|200|210|311|321|301|320|300|310|
020|010|021|000|011|001|120|110|121|100|111|101|220|210|221|200|211|201|320|310|321|300|311|301|
021|011|020|001|010|000|121|111|120|101|110|100|221|211|220|201|210|200|321|311|320|301|310|300|
100|101|200|201|300|301|000|001|210|211|310|311|010|011|110|111|320|321|020|021|120|121|220|221|
101|100|201|200|301|300|001|000|211|210|311|310|011|010|111|110|321|320|021|020|121|120|221|220|
110|120|210|220|310|320|010|020|200|221|300|321|000|021|100|121|301|311|001|011|101|111|201|211|
111|121|211|221|311|321|011|021|201|220|301|320|001|020|101|120|300|310|000|010|100|110|200|210|
120|110|220|210|320|310|020|010|221|200|321|300|021|000|121|100|311|301|011|001|111|101|211|201|
121|111|221|211|321|311|021|011|220|201|320|301|020|001|120|101|310|300|010|000|110|100|210|200|
200|300|100|301|101|201|210|310|000|311|001|211|110|320|010|321|011|111|120|220|020|221|021|121|
201|301|101|300|100|200|211|311|001|310|000|210|111|321|011|320|010|110|121|221|021|220|020|120|
210|310|110|320|120|220|200|300|010|321|020|221|100|301|000|311|021|121|101|201|001|211|011|111|
211|311|111|321|121|221|201|301|011|320|021|220|101|300|001|310|020|120|100|200|000|210|010|110|
220|320|120|310|110|210|221|321|020|300|010|200|121|311|021|301|000|100|111|211|011|201|001|101|
221|321|121|311|111|211|220|320|021|301|011|201|120|310|020|300|001|101|110|210|010|200|000|100|
300|200|301|100|201|101|310|210|311|000|211|001|320|110|321|010|111|011|220|120|221|020|121|021|
301|201|300|101|200|100|311|211|310|001|210|000|321|111|320|011|110|010|221|121|220|021|120|020|
310|210|320|110|220|120|300|200|321|010|221|020|301|100|311|000|121|021|201|101|211|001|111|011|
311|211|321|111|221|121|301|201|320|011|220|021|300|101|310|001|120|020|200|100|210|000|110|010|
320|220|310|120|210|110|321|221|300|020|200|010|311|121|301|021|100|000|211|111|201|011|101|001|
321|221|311|121|211|111|320|220|301|021|201|011|310|120|300|020|101|001|210|110|200|010|100|000|
```

Comment: If you are not wedded to lexicographic order, wouldn't this be akin to converting two values less than `n` to one value less than `n` in a consistent way?

Comment: @גלעדברקן I don't think so. Say we define f(R, n, i, j) as the function that takes some rank ordering R of permutations (so R is a list of unique permutations), n is the length of the permutations (elements 0 to n-1;  |R| = n!), and i and j are the indices of the two input permutations in R, then f(R, n, i, j) is the index of the output permutation in R. I don't care what R is, but I don't think it's a trivial problem. Maybe I'm misinterpreting your comment -- could you clarify or give an example?

Comment: Sorry, I mistook `n` for the number of permutations. In that case, what I meant was converting two values less than or equal to |R| to one value less than or equal to |R| in a consistent, non-trivial way.

Comment: @גלעדברקן Yes, that's the goal. The particular way in which it needs to be consistent is that R[f(R, n, i, j)] needs to be the permutation you get when you index into R[j] with the values of R[i]. Using lexicographic order for R is nice because we can translate between rank & permutation relatively quickly with Lehmer codes, which is a feature I'd like to retain even if I get a good answer to this question for some other ranking.

Comment: You could redefine a "permutation" `p` of `s` to mean `unrank(max(rank(s),rank(p)) - min(rank(s),rank(p)))`. But that way computing a permutation would require ranking `s` and `p`. Can you give us more context about how you might implement the function?

Comment: @גלעדברקן No; I can't redefine permutations. Also, when the two permutations are the same (so their ranks are the same), the output permutation can differ. Compare the 2nd example above to i=j=0 in lexicographic order. Under any R both of those would have max-min = 0, but the resulting permutations differ.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61708/discussion-between-dave-galvin-and--).

Comment: it looks like you have to solve giant (n! * n!) sudoku without calculating permutations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an algorithm to convert between permutations and ranks in linear time. That's not quite what I want, but is probably good enough. It turns out that the fact that I don't care about lexicographic order is important. The ranking this uses is weird. I'm going to give two functions, one that converts from a rank to a permutation, and one that does the inverse.

First, to unrank (go from rank to permutation)

```
Initialize:
n = length(permutation)
r = desired rank
p = identity permutation of n elements [0, 1, ..., n]

unrank(n, r, p)
  if n > 0 then
    swap(p[n-1], p[r mod n])
    unrank(n-1, floor(r/n), p)
  fi
end
```

Next, to rank:

```
Initialize:
p = input permutation
q = inverse input permutation (in linear time, q[p[i]] = i for 0 <= i < n)
n = length(p)

rank(n, p, q)
  if n=1 then return 0 fi
  s = p[n-1]
  swap(p[n-1], p[q[n-1]])
  swap(q[s], q[n-1])
  return s + n * rank(n-1, p, q)
end
```

That's the pseudocode. For my project I'll be careful to work with a copy of p so I don't mutate it when calculating its rank.

The running time of both of these is O(n).

There's a nice, readable paper explaining why this works: Ranking & Unranking Permutations in Linear Time, by Myrvold & Ruskey, Information Processing Letters Volume 79, Issue 6, 30 September 2001, Pages 281–284.

http://webhome.cs.uvic.ca/~ruskey/Publications/RankPerm/MyrvoldRuskey.pdf

Answer (score 0):

If, in addition to R, you are not wedded to a particular P either, we could redefine the permutation function to facilitate a possible answer. The function, `newPerm`, below would permute a list in relation to R with the same consistency as the permuting function that "indexes into."

The example below is not optimized for efficiency (e.g., ranking/unranking can be done in O(n)). The last two lines of output compare the redefined permuting function to the "indexing" permuting function - as you can see, they both generate the same number of unique permutations when mapped to the permutation set. The function, `f`, would be the answer to the question.

Haskell code:

```
import Data.List (sort,permutations)
import Data.Maybe (fromJust)

sortedPermutations = sort $ permutations [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]

rank p = fromJust (lookup p rs) where rs = zip sortedPermutations [0..]

unrank r = fromJust (lookup r ps) where ps = zip [0..] sortedPermutations

tradPerm p s = foldr (\a b -> s!!a : b) [] p

newPerm p s = unrank (f (rank p) (rank s))

f r1 r2 = let l = r1 - r2 in if l < 0 then length sortedPermutations + l else l
```

Output:

```
*Main Data.List> unrank 3
[0,1,2,3,5,6,4]

*Main Data.List> unrank 8
[0,1,2,4,5,3,6]

*Main Data.List> f 3 8
5035

*Main Data.List> newPerm [0,1,2,3,5,6,4] [0,1,2,4,5,3,6]
[6,5,4,3,0,2,1]

*Main Data.List> rank [6,5,4,3,0,2,1]
5035

*Main Data.List> length $ group $ sort $ map (tradPerm [1,2,5,0,4,3,6]) sortedPermutations
5040

*Main Data.List> length $ group $ sort $ map (newPerm [1,2,5,0,4,3,6]) sortedPermutations
5040
```

Comment: If "f 3 8 = 5035" means that indexing into the 8th permutation with elements of the 3rd permutation yields the 5035th permutation, and the 3rd and 8th permutation are as described in your output, then we should have "unrank 5035 = [0,1,2,4,3,6,5]. I.e., this doesn't seem to have the property that the output rank is the rank of the permutation you get by indexing into the 2nd permutation with the elements of the first permutation. I'm just basing this on the output you gave, since I don't know Haskell.

Comment: @DaveGalvin Thank you for your comment. I assume that what you are referring to as "indexing into" means "permuting"; that is, I am using the 3rd permutation to permute the 8th (I guess my `i` and `j` are switched in my example, oops). Since, in this instance, I am redefining "permutation" to mean `unrank (f (rank p) (rank s))`, my "indexing into" or "permuting" happens through the function `newPerm` which generates `[6,5,4,3,0,2,1]`. unrank 5035 also yields `[6,5,4,3,0,2,1]`, as it should. I haven't tested or proved it thoroughly, just trying something unconventional that might be consistent.

Comment: @DaveGalvin regarding Haskell - you can more or less read the code as you would math. `rank` and `unrank` simply look up the index or permutation in a list, `tradPerm` is how you would traditionally permute (by "indexing into").

Comment: Let n be any positive integer and R be any ranking of all the permutations of 0 through n-1. Let i and j be two ranks, and I and J the permutations that achieve those ranks under R. Then we want f(R,n,i,j) to be the rank of [J[I[0]], J[I[1]], J[I[2]], J[I[3]], ..., J[I[n-1]]] under R. That is, we want to use the elements of the first permutation as indices into the second permutation.

Comment: @DaveGalvin Yes, I understand that in your question you would like the "permutation" of the "permutation" in a traditional sense. I am defining "permuting" in a different way to make the function you are after trivial. Depending on how you would like to implement this whole thing, my idea may or may not prove useful.

Comment: I clarified the question to refer to permutations of permutations instead of indexing into permutations. I can't change what a permutation means.

Comment: @DaveGalvin I understand. Part of the reason I thought of it is that you said you are not wedded to a particular R. In that case, I thought, perhaps you might not be wedded to a particular P either. Permuting means taking an ordered list and changing the order. The function I suggested would do that in relation to R with the same consistency as the traditional permutation.